# Census data extraction for time series

Tags: time-series, census

I am trying to download the average population for AZ counties using `tidycensus`, using the code below. How can I download population data for a time series period from 2000-2019 (interpolating for years that do not have decennial census or acs data)

```
library(tidycensus)
library(tidyverse)
soc.2010 <- get_decennial(geography = "county", state = "AZ", year = 2010, variables = (c(pop="P001001")), survey="sf1")

soc.16 <- get_acs(geography = "county", year=2016, variables = (c(pop="B01003_001")),state="AZ", survey="acs5") %>% mutate(Year = "2016")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the tidycensus function, [`get_estimates()`](https://walker-data.com/tidycensus/reference/get_estimates.html) to get population estimates by county for each year beginning in 2010.

```r
library(tidycensus)
library(dplyr)

get_estimates(
  geography = "county",
  state = "AZ",
  product = "population",
  time_series = TRUE
  ) %>% 
  filter(DATE >= 3) %>% 
  mutate(year = DATE + 2007)
#> # A tibble: 300 x 6
#>    NAME                  DATE GEOID variable   value  year
#>    <chr>                <dbl> <chr> <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 Pima County, Arizona     3 04019 POP       981620  2010
#>  2 Pima County, Arizona     4 04019 POP       988381  2011
#>  3 Pima County, Arizona     5 04019 POP       993052  2012
#>  4 Pima County, Arizona     6 04019 POP       997127  2013
#>  5 Pima County, Arizona     7 04019 POP      1004229  2014
#>  6 Pima County, Arizona     8 04019 POP      1009103  2015
#>  7 Pima County, Arizona     9 04019 POP      1016707  2016
#>  8 Pima County, Arizona    10 04019 POP      1026391  2017
#>  9 Pima County, Arizona    11 04019 POP      1036554  2018
#> 10 Pima County, Arizona    12 04019 POP      1047279  2019
#> # ... with 290 more rows
```

The API returns somewhat confusing date codes that I've converted to years. See the [date code to year mapping for 2019 population estimates](https://www.census.gov/data/developers/data-sets/popest-popproj/popest/popest-vars/2019.html) for more information.

For years prior to 2010, the Census API uses a [different format](https://www.census.gov/data/developers/data-sets/popest-popproj/popest.2000-2010_Intercensals.html) that is not accessible via tidycensus. But here is an API call that gives you population by county by year for 2000 to 2010:

https://api.census.gov/data/2000/pep/int_population?get=GEONAME,POP,DATE_DESC&for=county:*&in=state:04

```
["Graham County, Arizona","33356","7/1/2001 population estimate","04","009"],
["Graham County, Arizona","33224","7/1/2002 population estimate","04","009"],
["Graham County, Arizona","32985","7/1/2003 population estimate","04","009"],
["Graham County, Arizona","32703","7/1/2004 population estimate","04","009"],
["Graham County, Arizona","32964","7/1/2005 population estimate","04","009"],
["Graham County, Arizona","33701","7/1/2006 population estimate","04","009"],
["Graham County, Arizona","35175","7/1/2007 population estimate","04","009"],
["Graham County, Arizona","36639","7/1/2008 population estimate","04","009"],
["Graham County, Arizona","37525","7/1/2009 population estimate","04","009"],
["Graham County, Arizona","37220","4/1/2010 Census 2010 population","04","009"],
```

Comment: Thank you so much.